# formatting 2 lists of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

below I have 2 list of dics, I would like to know how I can loop through both lists and find matching environments and ids and add the costs to my formatted_list where id == id and environment == environment.  I only want a prod and non prod pair of id's in my formatted_list.  My current logic is creating multiple id's in my formatted list. How can I just add costs to my formatted_ist from my results_ecs list?

```
def main(formatted_results_ecs, formatted_list):
ecs_deduction = 0
for ecs_cost in formatted_results_ecs:
    for cost_est in formatted_list:
        if ecs_cost["id"] == cost_est["id"] and ecs_cost["environment"] == cost_est["environment"]:
            combined_cost = ecs_cost["cost"] + cost_est["cost"]
            cost_est["cost"] = combined_cost
            ecs_deduction += combined_cost



if __name__ == '__main__':
    formatted_results_ecs = [
        {'id': 'ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394', 'cost': 3.2980019999999994, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4', 'cost': 215.82577600000002, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 291.61807799999997, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'a855d85f-65e4-40bb-a21f-6ceea77628cc', 'cost': 19.041902000000004, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'aa385029-afa6-4f1a-a1d9-d88b7d934699', 'cost': 2.033628000000001, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'adf44794-50eb-45db-9323-6ce5fd31699e', 'cost': 1120.8391390000004, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'b13a0676-6926-49db-808c-3c968a9278eb', 'cost': 15145.140081999996, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'e4c3c7b9-5941-4cf7-aa90-f63a142ccaf4', 'cost': 3319.4728399999995, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 6.0234558329471, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 7.9407999472248, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': '2d1e7f15-d3bb-4649-996e-a7afb55b7637', 'cost': 5.940205, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': '6841509d-1d68-4af3-b04e-8bc7e87d0c89', 'cost': 651.016164, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394', 'cost': 3.287444999999999, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4', 'cost': 214.46528800000002, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 291.55481199999997, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'aa385029-afa6-4f1a-a1d9-d88b7d934699', 'cost': 2.0193450000000013, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
    ]
    formatted_list = [
        {'id': 'ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394', 'cost': 13.431203414269257, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4', 'cost': 3.1723085934801296, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 602.0234558329471, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 607.9407999472248, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ff4f589f-2616-4f5e-9fb0-09e7ab3d200c', 'cost': 0.187242731922548, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ff2041fb-711f-4bca-a336-5c6ac07fb8f3', 'cost': 1.179409983e-06, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff2041fb-711f-4bca-a336-5c6ac07fb8f3', 'cost': 1.179409983e-06, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'fba58f4f-303c-4a20-86d3-294714c8db5c', 'cost': 14.494946621907866, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'f8780ef9-0211-486b-ac2d-1b85d6bcb9da', 'cost': 19.592325435434688, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'f8780ef9-0211-486b-ac2d-1b85d6bcb9da', 'cost': 19.288246392238705, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'f7f16766-1212-4747-9c98-7a37d125e850', 'cost': 0.8798593169569822, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'f7d59e13-cba1-4a13-af57-8c4aec3ee281', 'cost': 30.22516723291206, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'f7d59e13-cba1-4a13-af57-8c4aec3ee281', 'cost': 29.88632221088805, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'f742f6ea-01dc-4add-a283-6afa6656a87b', 'cost': 18.657917564221908, 'environment': 'prod'}
    ]
    main(formatted_list, formatted_results_ecs)
```

a good example id is ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18. This id shows up 4 times in the formatted_result_ecs list and im trying to add cost by env to my foratted_list.  Any breakdown or explanation of how this solution should work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would redo the second list into a dictionary where the key is `(id,environment)` and the value is `cost`.  Now, it's easy to check if the key exists and to update the data.

Comment: super helpful just a little over my head but I understand the concept

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I described above.  I mogrify the formatted list into a dictionary form, which makes the lookups easy.  I mogrify it back to the original form after.  In the Perl world, this is called a "Schwartzian transform".

```
from pprint import pprint
def main(formatted_results_ecs, formatted_list):
    # Reformat formatted list.
    fmt1 = {}
    for row in formatted_list:
        fmt1[(row['id'],row['environment'])] = row['cost']
    for row in formatted_results_ecs:
        key = (row['id'],row['environment'])
        if key in fmt1:
            fmt1[key] += row['cost']
        else:
            fmt1[key] = row['cost']
    pprint(fmt1)
    # return to original format.
    fmtl = [{'id': k[0], 'cost': v, 'environment': k[1]} for k,v in fmt1.items()]
    fmtl.sort(key=lambda k: k['id'])
    pprint(fmtl)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    formatted_results_ecs = [
        {'id': 'ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394', 'cost': 3.2980019999999994, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4', 'cost': 215.82577600000002, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 291.61807799999997, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'a855d85f-65e4-40bb-a21f-6ceea77628cc', 'cost': 19.041902000000004, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'aa385029-afa6-4f1a-a1d9-d88b7d934699', 'cost': 2.033628000000001, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'adf44794-50eb-45db-9323-6ce5fd31699e', 'cost': 1120.8391390000004, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'b13a0676-6926-49db-808c-3c968a9278eb', 'cost': 15145.140081999996, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'e4c3c7b9-5941-4cf7-aa90-f63a142ccaf4', 'cost': 3319.4728399999995, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 6.0234558329471, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 7.9407999472248, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': '2d1e7f15-d3bb-4649-996e-a7afb55b7637', 'cost': 5.940205, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': '6841509d-1d68-4af3-b04e-8bc7e87d0c89', 'cost': 651.016164, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394', 'cost': 3.287444999999999, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4', 'cost': 214.46528800000002, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 291.55481199999997, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'aa385029-afa6-4f1a-a1d9-d88b7d934699', 'cost': 2.0193450000000013, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
    ]
    formatted_list = [
        {'id': 'ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394', 'cost': 13.431203414269257, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4', 'cost': 3.1723085934801296, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 602.0234558329471, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 607.9407999472248, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ff4f589f-2616-4f5e-9fb0-09e7ab3d200c', 'cost': 0.187242731922548, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ff2041fb-711f-4bca-a336-5c6ac07fb8f3', 'cost': 1.179409983e-06, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff2041fb-711f-4bca-a336-5c6ac07fb8f3', 'cost': 1.179409983e-06, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'fba58f4f-303c-4a20-86d3-294714c8db5c', 'cost': 14.494946621907866, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'f8780ef9-0211-486b-ac2d-1b85d6bcb9da', 'cost': 19.592325435434688, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'f8780ef9-0211-486b-ac2d-1b85d6bcb9da', 'cost': 19.288246392238705, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'f7f16766-1212-4747-9c98-7a37d125e850', 'cost': 0.8798593169569822, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'f7d59e13-cba1-4a13-af57-8c4aec3ee281', 'cost': 30.22516723291206, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'f7d59e13-cba1-4a13-af57-8c4aec3ee281', 'cost': 29.88632221088805, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'f742f6ea-01dc-4add-a283-6afa6656a87b', 'cost': 18.657917564221908, 'environment': 'prod'}
    ]
    main( formatted_results_ecs, formatted_list )
```

Output:

```
{('2d1e7f15-d3bb-4649-996e-a7afb55b7637', 'prod'): 5.940205,
 ('6841509d-1d68-4af3-b04e-8bc7e87d0c89', 'prod'): 651.016164,
 ('a855d85f-65e4-40bb-a21f-6ceea77628cc', 'prod'): 19.041902000000004,
 ('aa385029-afa6-4f1a-a1d9-d88b7d934699', 'nonprod'): 2.0193450000000013,
 ('aa385029-afa6-4f1a-a1d9-d88b7d934699', 'prod'): 2.033628000000001,
 ('adf44794-50eb-45db-9323-6ce5fd31699e', 'prod'): 1120.8391390000004,
 ('b13a0676-6926-49db-808c-3c968a9278eb', 'prod'): 15145.140081999996,
 ('e4c3c7b9-5941-4cf7-aa90-f63a142ccaf4', 'prod'): 3319.4728399999995,
 ('f742f6ea-01dc-4add-a283-6afa6656a87b', 'prod'): 18.657917564221908,
 ('f7d59e13-cba1-4a13-af57-8c4aec3ee281', 'nonprod'): 29.88632221088805,
 ('f7d59e13-cba1-4a13-af57-8c4aec3ee281', 'prod'): 30.22516723291206,
 ('f7f16766-1212-4747-9c98-7a37d125e850', 'nonprod'): 0.8798593169569822,
 ('f8780ef9-0211-486b-ac2d-1b85d6bcb9da', 'nonprod'): 19.592325435434688,
 ('f8780ef9-0211-486b-ac2d-1b85d6bcb9da', 'prod'): 19.288246392238705,
 ('fba58f4f-303c-4a20-86d3-294714c8db5c', 'nonprod'): 14.494946621907866,
 ('ff2041fb-711f-4bca-a336-5c6ac07fb8f3', 'nonprod'): 1.179409983e-06,
 ('ff2041fb-711f-4bca-a336-5c6ac07fb8f3', 'prod'): 1.179409983e-06,
 ('ff4f589f-2616-4f5e-9fb0-09e7ab3d200c', 'prod'): 0.187242731922548,
 ('ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'nonprod'): 899.6017236658942,
 ('ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'prod'): 907.4996778944496,
 ('ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4', 'nonprod'): 217.63759659348014,
 ('ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4', 'prod'): 215.82577600000002,
 ('ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394', 'nonprod'): 16.718648414269257,
 ('ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394', 'prod'): 3.2980019999999994}
[{'cost': 5.940205,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': '2d1e7f15-d3bb-4649-996e-a7afb55b7637'},
 {'cost': 651.016164,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': '6841509d-1d68-4af3-b04e-8bc7e87d0c89'},
 {'cost': 19.041902000000004,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'a855d85f-65e4-40bb-a21f-6ceea77628cc'},
 {'cost': 2.033628000000001,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'aa385029-afa6-4f1a-a1d9-d88b7d934699'},
 {'cost': 2.0193450000000013,
  'environment': 'nonprod',
  'id': 'aa385029-afa6-4f1a-a1d9-d88b7d934699'},
 {'cost': 1120.8391390000004,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'adf44794-50eb-45db-9323-6ce5fd31699e'},
 {'cost': 15145.140081999996,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'b13a0676-6926-49db-808c-3c968a9278eb'},
 {'cost': 3319.4728399999995,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'e4c3c7b9-5941-4cf7-aa90-f63a142ccaf4'},
 {'cost': 18.657917564221908,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'f742f6ea-01dc-4add-a283-6afa6656a87b'},
 {'cost': 30.22516723291206,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'f7d59e13-cba1-4a13-af57-8c4aec3ee281'},
 {'cost': 29.88632221088805,
  'environment': 'nonprod',
  'id': 'f7d59e13-cba1-4a13-af57-8c4aec3ee281'},
 {'cost': 0.8798593169569822,
  'environment': 'nonprod',
  'id': 'f7f16766-1212-4747-9c98-7a37d125e850'},
 {'cost': 19.592325435434688,
  'environment': 'nonprod',
  'id': 'f8780ef9-0211-486b-ac2d-1b85d6bcb9da'},
 {'cost': 19.288246392238705,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'f8780ef9-0211-486b-ac2d-1b85d6bcb9da'},
 {'cost': 14.494946621907866,
  'environment': 'nonprod',
  'id': 'fba58f4f-303c-4a20-86d3-294714c8db5c'},
 {'cost': 1.179409983e-06,
  'environment': 'nonprod',
  'id': 'ff2041fb-711f-4bca-a336-5c6ac07fb8f3'},
 {'cost': 1.179409983e-06,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'ff2041fb-711f-4bca-a336-5c6ac07fb8f3'},
 {'cost': 0.187242731922548,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'ff4f589f-2616-4f5e-9fb0-09e7ab3d200c'},
 {'cost': 899.6017236658942,
  'environment': 'nonprod',
  'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18'},
 {'cost': 907.4996778944496,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18'},
 {'cost': 217.63759659348014,
  'environment': 'nonprod',
  'id': 'ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4'},
 {'cost': 215.82577600000002,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4'},
 {'cost': 16.718648414269257,
  'environment': 'nonprod',
  'id': 'ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394'},
 {'cost': 3.2980019999999994,
  'environment': 'prod',
  'id': 'ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try using below statement ( you may need to adjust your code to your need) , but mering dictionary could be a better option

```
result_set= [
        {'id': 'ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394', 'cost': 3.2980019999999994, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4', 'cost': 215.82577600000002, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 291.61807799999997, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'a855d85f-65e4-40bb-a21f-6ceea77628cc', 'cost': 19.041902000000004, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'aa385029-afa6-4f1a-a1d9-d88b7d934699', 'cost': 2.033628000000001, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'adf44794-50eb-45db-9323-6ce5fd31699e', 'cost': 1120.8391390000004, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'b13a0676-6926-49db-808c-3c968a9278eb', 'cost': 15145.140081999996, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'e4c3c7b9-5941-4cf7-aa90-f63a142ccaf4', 'cost': 3319.4728399999995, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 6.0234558329471, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 7.9407999472248, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': '2d1e7f15-d3bb-4649-996e-a7afb55b7637', 'cost': 5.940205, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': '6841509d-1d68-4af3-b04e-8bc7e87d0c89', 'cost': 651.016164, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394', 'cost': 3.287444999999999, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4', 'cost': 214.46528800000002, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 291.55481199999997, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'aa385029-afa6-4f1a-a1d9-d88b7d934699', 'cost': 2.0193450000000013, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
    ]
print(result_set)

interim_list = [
        {'id': 'ffd07d03-e10b-4d60-8e28-e4ab617bf394', 'cost': 13.431203414269257, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ffc87314-16e4-4c77-b5ec-f34066458ce4', 'cost': 3.1723085934801296, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 602.0234558329471, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff66d353-6644-4c61-9c22-204960d65a18', 'cost': 607.9407999472248, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ff4f589f-2616-4f5e-9fb0-09e7ab3d200c', 'cost': 0.187242731922548, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'ff2041fb-711f-4bca-a336-5c6ac07fb8f3', 'cost': 1.179409983e-06, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'ff2041fb-711f-4bca-a336-5c6ac07fb8f3', 'cost': 1.179409983e-06, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'fba58f4f-303c-4a20-86d3-294714c8db5c', 'cost': 14.494946621907866, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'f8780ef9-0211-486b-ac2d-1b85d6bcb9da', 'cost': 19.592325435434688, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'f8780ef9-0211-486b-ac2d-1b85d6bcb9da', 'cost': 19.288246392238705, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'f7f16766-1212-4747-9c98-7a37d125e850', 'cost': 0.8798593169569822, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'f7d59e13-cba1-4a13-af57-8c4aec3ee281', 'cost': 30.22516723291206, 'environment': 'prod'},
        {'id': 'f7d59e13-cba1-4a13-af57-8c4aec3ee281', 'cost': 29.88632221088805, 'environment': 'nonprod'},
        {'id': 'f742f6ea-01dc-4add-a283-6afa6656a87b', 'cost': 18.657917564221908, 'environment': 'prod'}
    ]
print(interim_list)

def merge_list_result(result_set, interim_list):
  final_list = {**result_set, **interim_list}
  for id, value in final_list.id():
    if id in result_set & id in interim_list:
      final_list[id] = [value, result_set[id]]
  return final_list

  final_list = merge_final_result(result_set, interim_list)
  print(final_list)
```

Comment: If you are going to post code, PLEASE format it as code.  I'll fix it this time.

Comment: Your code has many problems.  You can't say `final_list.id()`; it's a dictionary.  `final_list` is not a list, it's a dictionary.  You should use the word `and` instead of `&`.  And you are not doing the processing he wanted.  Did you try your code before posting?